# Phonegap build (Could not find aapt2-proto.jar)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

Created new project with cordova and now i'm unable to run it:
cordova run android:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
```

In build.gradle `google()` repository presents in `buildscript` and `allprojects`
Any suggestions?

A bit weird that i have this line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

And script tries to load 0.3.1...

Comment: [Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4707790)

Comment: That didn't helped(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When importing cordova app to android studio it asks for gradle update, CANCEL IT!!!!
[image]