# Android CI build: Could not find aapt2-proto.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, jcenter

I have failing build on a Bitbucket CI server:

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
```

I searched similar questions that suggested the Google Maven repository is missing, but I am not missing it. Top level build file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

And my app level build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: opening https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar in browser gives 404, could it be broken jcenter / the library was moved ?

Comment: check here also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52979557/8034839

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try moving the `google()` method to the top of its execution block.

Maybe it's the order of repositories it searches in that causes the issue.

So for example, change this:

```
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  google() // from here
  mavenCentral()
}
```

To this:

```
repositories {
  google() // to here
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

If that doesn't help, instead of calling the `google()` method, try changing it to this:

```
maven {
  url 'https://maven.google.com/'
  name 'Google'
}
```

**UPDATE**

If all of the above didn't help - make sure your `gradle` version is at least `3.0.0`:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

And the `gradle-wrapper` version is at least `4.1`:

Usually located here: `project_name/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-2-0)

Comment: A problem occurred configuring root project 'XXXXXXXXXx'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

     Searched in the following locations:

         https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

Comment: This in combination with upgrading the gradle wrapper version to 4.10.2 worked for me

Comment: Moving google() to the very top, before maven and jcenter solved it for me on Android Studio 3.2.1.

Answer (score 22):

Upgrading the Gradle wrapper (in gradle-wrapper.properties) to gradle-4.10.2-all.zip fixed the problem to me.

Comment: Upgrading from gradle wrapper version 4.6 to 4.10.2 did the trick for me!

Comment: Upgrading Gradle worked but had to update kotlin-stdlib-common to 1.3.0-rc-198 too (131 before).

Comment: upgrading the wrapper version gives --- Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.0-rc-131 --- error. How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

#### Update Gradle Version

From the android gradle [release page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) you can check compatible version for your gradle plugin.

Update gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` located inside `yourProject/gradle/wrapper`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.0-all.zip
```

> ```
> Plugin version  Required Gradle version
>
>    2.3.0+             3.3+
>    3.0.0+             4.1+
>    3.1.0+             4.4+
> ```

**Note that order matters. `google()` should be top of any plugin repo.**

### For Android Studio version > 3.0

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google() // move it to top
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' // your Android Studio Version
  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // move it to top
      jcenter()
}
```

> `google()` plugin is needed since Android Studio version 3.0 or higher.

### For Android Studio version < 3.0

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       name 'Google'
      }
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' // your Android Studio Version
  }
} 
allprojects {
  repositories {
      maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       name 'Google'
      }
      jcenter()
}
```