# Flutter Error on Android: Could not find aapt2-proto.jar

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter project failed to build today with the following error:

> Where: Build file 'D:\Dev\Flutter\Projects\Misc\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle'
>   line: 26
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
> >     Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >              https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

I also started a brand new Flutter project in Android Studio, without changing anything, and got the same error.

I am running Android Studio 3.2.1 (9 October) build on Windows 10 64-bit.

This is my Flutter doctor output:

```
> D:\Dev\Flutter\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color doctor Doctor
> summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [√] Flutter
> (Channel master, v0.10.2-pre.30, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.17134.345], locale en-AU) [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3) [√] Android Studio
>     X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
>     X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality. [√] Connected device (1 available)
> 
> • No issues found! Process finished with exit code 0
```

*(Ignore the Flutter and Dart plugin-not-installed warnings, they are always there for me although everything works)*

I have tried other [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944351/android-ci-build-could-not-find-aapt2-proto-jar/52944600#52944600) such as making sure the google() repository is on top of the Gradle build files, but no luck.

Comment: i'm currently on the same bug

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22790 this refer to this i think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [couldn't locate lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar for flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945041/couldnt-locate-lint-gradle-api-26-1-2-jar-for-flutter-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing google() in file:  flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#L21

Should be resolved after merge https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397

Comment: Thanks! This worked. How did you even figure that out :-)