# Issue after updating flutter and android studio

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Hi I recently update flutter and my android studio and then I saw this error below:

[enter here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No3d5.png)

android/BuildGradlew:

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/buildgradlew:

---

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "ASDADED"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.1'
}
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.17134.345], locale es-AR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[!] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

I search here and y found a lot of answers but I cant solve it.

I try to put de maven repository or downgrade the plugins but I have the same error.

Comment: That's an issue that pops up quite often recently https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23404

Comment: Might be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: I made those changes but I still have the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an issue that pops up quite often recently

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23404

A possible fix is waiting for approval https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23404#issuecomment-432205806

Answer (score 0):

When you build an app bundle, it will increment version number and code automatically based on pubspec.yaml file.

**try**

```
flutter build appbundle
```