# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq"

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

This is my project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.ramin.quiz'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:7.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This line get error on MainApplication.class

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(MainApplication.this);
```

This line get error on menuHomeScreenActivity.class

```
Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
```

my logcat:

> ```
> 10-27 19:55:14.008 17432-17432/com.ramin.quiz E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> ```
>
> Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzark.zzbl(Unknown Source:0)
>               at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source:0)
>               at com.ramin.quiz.application.MainApplication.getDefaultTracker(**MainApplication.java:40**)
>               at com.ramin.quiz.activity.MenuHomeScreenActivity.onCreate(**MenuHomeScreenActivity.java:153**)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzark.zzbl(Unknown Source:0) 
>               at com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source:0) 
>               at com.ramin.quiz.application.MainApplication.getDefaultTracker(**MainApplication.java:40**) 
>               at com.ramin.quiz.activity.MenuHomeScreenActivity.onCreate(**MenuHomeScreenActivity.java:153**) 
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) 
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
>             Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location
>   /data/app/com.ramin.quiz-RNjLhiGfgiVubfbHvVcKDQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: i try that but still i get that error

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't always work, but try this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.
It is meant for apps that are getting errors due to their size.

You would add this to your dependencies:

`dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}`

For more explanation please read the article linked.