# Ionic - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. Could not find play-services-tasks-license.aar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

When trying to run the Ionic app in android this error appears

What went wrong:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find play-services-tasks-license.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0).

  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks-license/11.8.0/play-services-tasks-license-11.8.0.aar
```

Does anyone has the same problem and knows how to solve it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: I tried that yesterday. It did not work. But thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?