# error: package com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui does not exist

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

After updating from android SDK(25) to SDK(26), facing many problem.
then I want to upgrade to the latest version possible.
Currently, work with SDK(28) but I have trouble related google play service map/location.
I tried to change library version severally.

Can anyone please help me to fix this ?

This error happens on google map api related code.

Error:

> error: cannot find symbol class Place
>   error: package com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui does not exist
>   error: package com.google.android.gms.vision.text does not exist
>   error: cannot find symbol class PlaceSelectionListener
>   error: cannot find symbol class PlaceAutocompleteFragment
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   error: cannot find symbol class GeoPoint

project - build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
        google()
    }
}
```

app - build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('signature/debug-key.keystore')
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("signature/release-key.keystore")
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lovelain.getfinedustlevel"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    useLibrary('org.apache.http.legacy')

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944600/4255978

Comment: thanks, but still not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried to add Google Places API - `com.google.android.gms:play-services-places` and Mobile Vision API - `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision`? This was connected in your error.

Comment: you're right, added some libraries and code modification.

Answer (score 3):

Solved,

Updating SDK, not only map/location api but also other parts need.

and related Geopoint problem, it is modify code.

following is app - build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':library')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
}
```

thanks for support.