# When importing libgdx project to eclipse I get Gradle error

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

Whenever trying to import my LIBGDX project to eclipse that I just now created I get this error from eclipse:

[The error was really long so I made a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GJN7nndN)
First bit of the error:

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.

 A problem occurred configuring root project 'Endro'.
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.
```

I'm new to this area of programing and I have no clue how to go about fixing this stuff. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I found this error in my stack trace:

> Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).

and found a post with an answer that fixed the issue here:

> [Android CI build: Could not find aapt2-proto.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944351/android-ci-build-could-not-find-aapt2-proto-jar)